# Variable path in a loop

Tags: r, loops, path

I would like to get this loop to work. I am trying to save different dataframes with different names at once. I don't know how to get the path part of the code to vary with i:

```
for (i in specific)  {
  write.dta(get(paste0("degreeS", i)), "D:/Educacion/PeerEffects/",paste0( "degreeS", i,".dta"))

}
```

Comment: `"D:/Educacion/PeerEffects/",paste0( "degreeS", i,".dta")` won't produce a concatenated string. You have to wrap things up into `paste`, e.g. `paste("filename_", i, ".txt", sep = "")`.

Comment: I already solved the problem using the command I wrote on my answer. Thanks anyway, now I understand what was going wrong in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to use the command `file.path()`. This solved the problem

```
for (i in specific) {
write.dta(get(paste0("degreeS", i)), file.path("D://Educacion//PeerEffects//", paste0("degreeS", i,".dta")))
}
```